# How to get width difference between the canvas and a scaled image and do an efficient PingPong effect in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the width difference between the canvas and a image which is scaled by `CanvasScaler` in order to create translation between the image and his border.

**Illustration:**
[image: Illustration]

How get the size of the red arrow?

**[EDIT 1]**

The code snippet bellow give me a possible correct result

```cs
var dist = (canvasRectTransform.rect.width - image.sprite.rect.width) / 2;
```

But It seems to be incorrect:

```cs
public class Background : Monobehaviour 
{
        private float dist;
        private float _percentage;
        private float _currentLerpTime;`
        private readonly Dictionary<LerpDirection, Func<Vector3>> _lerpDirectionActions;

        public float lerpTime;
          
        void Awake()
        {
            var image = GetComponent<Image>();
            var canvasRectTransform = GetComponentInParent<RectTransform>();
            dist  = (canvasRectTransform.rect.width - image.sprite.rect.width) / 2;
            _lerpDirectionActions = new Dictionary<LerpDirection, Func<Vector3>>
            {
                [LerpDirection.Left] = LerpToLeft, 
                [LerpDirection.Right] = LerpToRight
            };
        }

        private Vector3 Lerp()
        {
            return Vector3.Lerp(
                transform.position, 
                _lerpDirectionActions[lerpDirection].Invoke(), // will call LerpToRight or LerpToLeft
                _percentage
            );
        }

        private float LerpX => Lerp().x;
        
        
        private Vector3 LerpToRight()
        {
            return new Vector3(transform.position.x - dist, transform.position.y);
        }

        private Vector3 LerpToLeft()
        {
            return new Vector3(transform.position.x + dist , transform.position.y);
        }

        void Update() 
        {

             _currentLerpTime += Time.deltaTime;
             _percentage = _currentLerpTime / lerpTime;
             var localPositionX = tranform.position.x;

             var mustGoRight = localPositionX <= 0 && lerpDirection == LerpDirection.Right;
             var mustGoLeft = localPositionX >= dist && lerpDirection  == LerpDirection.Left;

             if (mustGoLeft || mustGoRight)
             {
                direction = direction.Invert(); // invert direction
                Reset();
             }
             
             tranform.position =  new Vector3(LerpX, tranform.position.y)
        }

}
```

The `Background` script is applied to the **Background** GameObject.

```cs
_lerpDirectionActions[lerpDirection].Invoke()
```

This code above will invoke the right function for lerping on left or on right.

**Illustration:**
[image: issue]

The translation change his direction but not when the canvas is on the border on the image.

Comment: `(canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width - image.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width) / 2f` ?

Comment: yes it works but i'm getting a strange behavior i will edit my answer

Comment: I dont see what you mean .. in the gif you should it never reaches the border before it ends .. what is your actual goal? The sentences `give me a correct result` and `But it seems to be incorrect` are a bit contradictory ^^ Your script seems not to be complete .. at least it is hard to tell how you move the objects

Comment: `Scale` is `1,1,1` for both right?

Comment: for both object the scale are `1,1,1`, look the updated gif the translation stop but not at the end of the image.

Comment: Where is `_percentage` coming from and what is in your `_lerpDirectionActions`?

Comment: _lerpDirectionActions will invoke the right function for lerping on left or on right.

Comment: I have updated the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you are searching for would be

```c#
var difference = (canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width - image.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width) / 2f;
```

Your script looks quite complicated to be honest.

Why not simply put it all into one single [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) using [`Mathf.PingPong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html) which does exactly what you are currently controlling with your direction flags and actions

> PingPongs the value t, so that it is never larger than length and never smaller than 0.
>
> The returned value will move back and forth between 0 and length.

```c#
public Canvas canvas;
public Image image;

// Time in seconds to finish the movement from one extreme to the other
public float duration = 1;

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine (LerpForthAndBack());
}

private IEnumerator LerpForthAndBack()
{
    var difference = (canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width - image.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width) / 2f;

    var maxPosition = Vector3.right * difference;
    var minPosition = Vector3.left * difference;

    // Hugh? :O
    // -> This is actually totally fine in a Coroutine
    //    as long as you yield somewhere within it
    while(true)
    {
        image.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(minPosition, maxPosition, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time / duration, 1));
        
        // "Pause" the routine, render the frame and
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

ofcourse you could also do the same still in `Update`

```c#
private Vector3 minPosition;
private Vector3 maxPosition;

private void Start()
{
    var difference = (canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width - image.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width) / 2f;

    maxPosition = Vector3.right * difference;
    minPosition = Vector3.left * difference;
}

private void Update()
{
    image.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(minPosition, maxPosition, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time / duration, 1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips for using a Coroutine, I will try your snippet for getting the distance.

Comment: [`Mathf.PingPong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html) can be a good solution.

Comment: No pro happens to all of us ;) I just noted that in my examples I forgot to put in the `PingPong` ^^ updated now

Comment: I will edit the topic also by adding a hint for the `Mathf.PingPong` solution

Comment: What does the `length` parameter of `Mathf.PingPong` do?

Comment: @loic.lopez it is basically the maximum value